# Cannot convert List<Moq.Mock<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase>> to List<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a unit test where I'm mocking HttpPostedFileBase files and placing them in a list. The unit test is then calling a mail service like this (irrelevant parameters like to, from, subject is left out)

```
[Test]
public void SendMailWithFile()
{
    bool result = Services.Mail.MailService.SendMailWithFile(uploadedFiles);
```

uploadedFiles variable is like this : `List<Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>> uploadedFiles`

The mailService (which the unit test calls) is like this:

```
public static bool SendMailWithFile(List<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadedFiles)
```

Now everything should be okay, the mocked list does contains files (meaning it is not empty), but I'm getting this error.

cannot convert from

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<Moq.Mock<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase>
```

to

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `Object` property to get the mocked object (`HttpPostedFileBase` in your case) from the `Mock<T>` object.

This should do it:

```
bool result = Services.Mail.MailService.SendMailWithFile(
    uploadedFiles.Select(x => x.Object).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks Yacoub. I didn't think of that.